# Chef and Knife to bootstrap ec2 - OpenSSL::PKey::RSAError: private key needed.: no start line

Tags: ubuntu, chef-infra

I am a newbie trying to bootstrap and ec2 instance and nothing works with chef.

1. I am using chef server
2. My dev machine has a username of *ubuntu*.  I want to keep it the same name as ubuntu for ec2.

I tried this command.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/.chef$ knife ec2 server create -x ubuntu -r "role[testredis]" --region ap-southeast-1 -Z ap-southeast-1a -i ami-ae1a5dfc -f t1.micro -S testpem -I ~/.ec2/testpem.pem -S knife --ssh-user ubuntu
```

And I got the following output

```
ERROR: You have not provided a valid image (AMI) value.  Please note the short option for this value recently changed from '-i' to '-I'.
```

I then tried the below.

```
knife bootstrap ec2-46-137-231-241.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com -r "role[testredis]" -x ubuntu -i ~/.ec2/sg_development.pem --sudo
```

And I got the following output

```
ec2-46-137-231-241.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com /usr/bin/knife
ec2-46-137-231-241.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com /usr/bin/shef
ec2-46-137-231-241.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com Successfully installed chef-0.10.8
ec2-46-137-231-241.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com 1 gem installed
ec2-46-137-231-241.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com [Fri, 23 Mar 2012 23:56:02 +0000] INFO: *** Chef 0.10.8 ***
ec2-46-137-231-241.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com [Fri, 23 Mar 2012 23:56:03 +0000] INFO: Client key /etc/chef/client.pem is not present - registering
ec2-46-137-231-241.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com [Fri, 23 Mar 2012 23:56:03 +0000] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
ec2-46-137-231-241.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com [Fri, 23 Mar 2012 23:56:03 +0000] FATAL: OpenSSL::PKey::RSAError: private key needed.: no start line
```

I notice that the **/etc/chef/client.pem** on the  ec2 instance is the pem on the dev computer where I ran the knife command.

So, what do I do?  Is it node name clashing?

Answer (score 6):

It looks like have a missing or malformed validation key. You need this from your **chef-server** or **Opscode Hosted Chef** account in order to register new nodes with the server. Check your config in **.chef/knife.rb**. You need a validation key (typically '`ORGNAME-validator.pem`') and it  is NOT the same as the client.pem.

http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Authentication+and+Authorization